# Can I generate Vim syntax files for whole sentences?

Tags: vim

For example, I would like to generate a syntax: "The file was created", which I would like to be shown by the syntax completion engine when I 
type for example "The fil".

Where should I put this file in order for it to be loaded for any type of file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use abbreviations:

```
iabbrev fcr The file was created
```

See `:help abbreviations`.

Or a snippet engine like [Snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) or [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).